# Image upload in folder mvc 5 C#

Tags: image, file-upload, directory, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to upload an image and save it in a certain folder of the server I get error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` in the `file.SaveAs(path)` line.

View:

[image]

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult LoadImage()
    {


        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //String path = Server.MapPath("~/img/" + file.FileName);
        if (file != null)
        {

            String pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            String path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), pic);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UnauthorizedAccessException means:

- The caller does not have the required permission to the folder.
- The file is an executable file that is in use.
- Path specified a read-only file.

[More Info on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Workaround:  Using Server Folder instead of full path

Create an Image Folder In solution(or any your choice) as a storage for your images..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            //Get the file name 
            var pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            //Get the folder in the server
            var imagesDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/image/");
            var imgPath = imagesDir + pic;
            file.SaveAs((imgPath));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home", null);
    }
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The possible causes of this exception are:

- Permission not granted to the folder where you are uploading the images. (Provide read write permission to the folder if not given)
- The folder in which you are uploading is read only.
- The file is an executable which may be in use.

Hope this helps.